# Why can I access an iFrame but not its contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to access the contents of an iFrame and I'm getting nowhere.

I have this:

```
that.findGadget = $.fn.findGadget = function (root) {
    var root = root || this;
    if (root[0].tagName === "IFRAME") {
       root = root[0].contentDocument || root[0].contentWindow.document;
    }
    console.log(root);
```

};

I'm calling the function on the iFrame itself like so:

```
// options is my configuration object with id/src/...
var newHTML = document.createElement("iframe");
newHTML.setAttribute("src", options.src);
newHTML.setAttribute("frameborder", 0);
newHTML.setAttribute("data-id", options.id);
// add iFrame to page
// options.parent is a $(element)
newParentElement = options.parent.parent()[0];
options.parent.replaceWith( newHTML );

// select
var newRootElement = newParentElement.querySelectorAll(
    '[data-id="'+options.id+'"]'
  );
// calling on $('iframe')
$( newRootElement[0] ).findGadget();
...
```

My if statement inside `findGadget` works allright, so `root` is set to `document` of the iFrame. However I'm stuck from there, because everything else I'm trying:

```
root.body
root.body.innerHTML
$(root).find('div');
$('iframe').contents();
```

is undefined or an empty selector.

**Question**:
How do I correctly access the elements of an iFrame? Could the problem be that the contents haven't been loaded? I'm working on localstorage, so all files are from the same "domain".

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is the iframe completely loaded? Is it in the same domain?

Comment: same domain: yes. How can I check if it's loaded?

Comment: What is `options.src`? Your mention of local storage implies that it might be a `data:` URI.

Comment: @Quentin: something like "files/foo.html"

Comment: you have to check if the iframe is loaded first before you access its contents

Comment: Any console errors? I am currently commenting on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682987 which appears to be the same issue if you are browsing form you file system.

Comment: @HBP: Nope. But I just checked an answer. My problem was I should have triggered the function after the iFrame loaded instead of just calling it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, you need to wait until the iframe content has loaded. Using jQuery:

```
$('iframe').load(function () {                        
    // access the iframe content
});
```

Comment: The `load` did it for me. Because now `this` was the iframe with contents. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider following:

1) I'd recommend to fire the `findGadget()` function when iframe is loaded. You can achieve this by calling it from within the iframe's page itself or by putting whole `$(newRootElement[0] ).findGadget();` into

```
$(newRootElement[0]).ready(function (){
    // here
});
```

2) I recommend using only `contentWindow` as it's fully compatible with all browsers (tested).